Langchain js createRetrievalChain error Prompt must include a "context" variable
Using RetrievalQAChain is going to get deprecated so I am trying to use createRetrievalChain instead. But I am getting the following error
throw new Error(`Prompt must include a "${DOCUMENTS_KEY}" variable`);
              ^

Error: Prompt must include a "context" variable

This is my code, I am using google gen ai model
import { CSVLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/csv";
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter"
import { GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/google-genai";
import { HNSWLib } from "@langchain/community/vectorstores/hnswlib";
import { ChatGoogleGenerativeAI } from "@langchain/google-genai";
import { RetrievalQAChain } from "langchain/chains";
import { createRetrievalChain } from "langchain/chains/retrieval"
import { ChatPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate } from "@langchain/core/prompts";
import { createStuffDocumentsChain } from "langchain/chains/combine_documents";

const loader = new CSVLoader("./bookmarks_table_rows.csv");

const docs = await loader.load();

const splitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
  chunkSize: 1000, 
  chunkOverlap: 200
})

// chunks are created
const splittedDocs = await splitter.splitDocuments(docs)

const embeddings =  new GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings({
  model: "embedding-001",
  apiKey: KEY,
})

const vectorStore = await HNSWLib.fromDocuments(
  splittedDocs,
  embeddings
);

const model = new ChatGoogleGenerativeAI({
  model: "gemini-1.5-flash-latest",
  maxOutputTokens: 2048,
  apiKey: KEY
});

const vectorStoreRetriever = vectorStore.asRetriever()

// const chain = RetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorStoreRetriever)

const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(`Answer the user's question: {input}`);

const combineDocsChain = await createStuffDocumentsChain({
  model,
  prompt,
});

const chain = await createRetrievalChain({
  combineDocsChain,
  vectorStoreRetriever,
});

const question = "what are all the type present in the data ?"

const answer = await chain.invoke({
  input: question
})

console.log("ans", answer);

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is much appreciated

UPDATE:
adding context in the prompt has fixed the issue
const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(Answer the user's question: {input} {context});
But now getting another error Error: Expected a Runnable, function or object

UPDATE: The above error as been fixed with this , adding the llm key
const combineDocsChain = await createStuffDocumentsChain({
  llm: model,
  prompt,
});

Now stuck in an error that says ` const cleanedText = this.stripNewLines ? text.replace(/\n/g, " ") : text;
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')`

I'm currently facing the same issue. Got up to your last solution (adding llm key). Now I'm stuck at Expected a Runnable, function or object.. Have you been able to fix yours?

Fixed my issue by using the right llm object (OpenAI from @langchain/openai). I'm now stuck at TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

I too have not found a solution to this yet

please define the context variable in your prompt template
use this
const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(`you are a helpful assistant {context} Answer the user's question: {input}`);
instead of this
const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(`Answer the user's question: {input}`);
this is not enough you need to pass value while calling invoke method you need to pass context value.In your case
const answer = await chain.invoke({ input: question, context: vectorStoreRetriever })
I hope this is helpful
